# Description of the Webpage when searched on google

Tags: html, seo

I want to change the description of my webpage when searched on google but i don't know how will i do it, i also don't know what to search on google. this is the current description of my webpage when I searched it on google,the text below are displayed on the footer of my webpage:

***Home · Register · login. Advertisement. Tweet TryOnGlasses© Copyright 2014. All rights reserved.***

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: i added seo on the tags, just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the meta tag for description is the way to describe your page in a short way to the search engine:

```
<meta name="description" content="My description" />
```

This goes inside the `<head></head>` tags in your html file.

Comment: thank you. but it's not working. when i searched my webpage the description is still the same, do i need to do something else other than putting that meta tag?

Comment: @chitcharonko I'm not an SEO expert, but I do know it takes time for Google and other search engines to update meta tags. How long? I couldn't say. You can do some research on how long it will take to update.

Comment: okay, thank you so much, you gave me an idea on what to search on google. :)

Comment: i searched my site on google a while ago, then the description was changed the way i want it to be, and guess what it is first on the list, last time it was on the fifth spot, you are really right that it takes time to work.